# NLog FallBackgroup log exception on fail to log

Tags: c#, exception, logging, nlog, fallback

I have got following in my NLog config.

```
<targets>
  <target xsi:type="FallbackGroup" name="MainTarget">
    <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" name="MyDataBaseLogger">
      <target xsi:type="MyTarget" />
    </target>
    <target xsi:type="AsyncWrapper" name="MyFileLogger">
      <target xsi:type="MyTarget2" />
    </target>        
  </target>
</targets>
```

MyTarget.cs is as follows:

```
   [Target("MyTarget")]
    public class MyTarget : TargetWithLayout
    {
        protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            WriteLogEvent(logEvent);
        }

        protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo[] logEvents)
        {
            foreach (var logEvent in logEvents)
            {
                WriteLogEvent(logEvent.LogEvent);
            }
        }

        private void WriteLogEvent(LogEventInfo logEvent)
        {
            throw new Exception("My Logger Failed");
            Debug.WriteLine(logEvent.FormattedMessage);
        }
    }
```

MyTarget2.cs

```
[Target("MyTarget2")]
public class MyTarget2 : TargetWithLayout
{
    protected override void Write(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        WriteLogEvent(logEvent);
    }

    protected override void Write(AsyncLogEventInfo[] logEvents)
    {
        foreach (var logEvent in logEvents)
        {
            WriteLogEvent(logEvent.LogEvent);
        }
    }

    private void WriteLogEvent(LogEventInfo logEvent)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(logEvent.FormattedMessage);
    }
}
```

So in this scenario if MyTarget fails (in this example it does), it goes to MyTarget2 which it does. But how do I log the exception/message that MyTarget has failed to log the exception in first instance?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

The only way to know why the target failed is to enable the internal log and look at the output. The internal log can be enabled like describe here, https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Internal-Logging

Comment: So any failed logging attempts will be propagated to internal log?